# Material auto complete text view drop down not showing properly in depend on another auto complete text view selection

Tags: android

I had used two material auto complete text view (act as spinner - present and OT hours) for my app.  If I click present spinner item (Yes) then OT hours spinner items will show.

[image]

but I can select NO in present spinner then OT hours spinner item can't show drop-down.

[image]

Actually my problem was if I again selected YES in present spinner there is no change in OT spinner it will not show drop-down item.

[image]

My code

```
    spinPresent1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(spinPresent1.getText().toString().equals("Yes")){
                    spinOT1.setEnabled(true);
                    spinOT1.setText(spinOT1.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString(), false);
                    spinOT1.showDropDown();
            }
                if(spinPresent1.getText().toString().equals("No")){
                    spinOT1.setEnabled(false);
                    spinOT1.setText("00 -  No OT", false);
                    spinOT1.dismissDropDown();
                    spinOT1.setDropDownHeight(0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution

To set Id for text input layout in XML and use the method of setEnabled for enable or disable the layout

That's it good luck!